# How to change the y-axis label for reusable chart in D3js

Tags: d3.js

I made a reusable bar chart "barChart.js", and in my "main.js" I used it for making 3 different charts. Each chart has different y-axis labels, I could not figure how to change the y-axis label in my "main.js" file. I define y-axis in my reusable "barChart.js" as:

```
var ylabel = g.selectAll(".tick text")
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 300 - margin.left)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Value");

g.select(".y.axis")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(10))
    .enter().append("ylabel");
```

and in my "main.js" file I tried to change the label from "Value" in one of my chart to speed like this:

```
var speed = d3.select('#speed')
        .datum(carData.speed.all())
        .call(speedBarChart);

    speed.select(".x.axis")
        .selectAll(".tick text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-45) translate(-7,0)");
    speed.select(".y.axis")
        .select("ylabel")
        .selectAll(".tick text")
        .text("Speed");
```

But clearly it did not work, any ideas about how I can do this I am using D3js V-4?

Answer (score 2):

Your second selection, for `.y.axis` is when you are currently inside the selection for the `.x.axis` object. So d3 is looking for the Y-axis inside your X-axis - which returns nothing.

You need to select the speed graph in general, then select each axis in turn. Try updating the code to something like this:

```
var speed = d3.select('#speed')
    .datum(carData.speed.all())
    .call(speedBarChart);

speed.select(".x.axis")
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45) translate(-7,0)")

speed.select(".y.axis")
    .select("text")
    .text("Speed");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but now, it doesn't show the y-axis at all, any idea?

Comment: I've updated the code - there should have been a `.select(text)` after the selection of the y-axis. You might need to add a class to your axis label, and then select by that, because otherwise `select(text)` might select one of the tick labels if they are enabled

Comment: Thanks! you are right. However, I am very new to this, I couldn't figure it out by myself. I update my code, can you  tell me what I am doing wrong?